# Richfaces + Icefaces Ajax Push

Tags: ajax, seam, richfaces, comet, icefaces

I have a project using Jboss Seam + Richfaces and I want to use comet (ajax push).

I've been reading some stuff and found Icefaces ajax push really interesting.

The problem is that I can´t get icefaces and richfaces work together... not sure if I'm configuring it right.

Somebody already did this? What are my alternatives using Jboss Seam?

I read about Atmosphere framework and its annotations but I didn´t figured out how to use it with Jboss Seam.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a4j supports Ajax push: [Here's a demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/push.jsf).

Edit,
Found two more:

http://relation.to/12032.lace

http://blog.eitchnet.ch/?p=57

Comment: Actually I wanted to use a long polling method like Icefaces do. This constant call to server that richfaces does is going to kill the server. It almost killed mine just developing, imagine with a lot of users connected...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I wanted to use a long polling method like Icefaces do.
This constant call to server that richfaces does is going to kill the server.
It almost killed mine just developing, imagine with a lot of users connected...

Answer (score 0):

As far I know integrating IceFaces an Richfaces will be possible when theirs JSF 2.0 versions will be released = in IceFaces 2.0 and RichFaces 4.0.